# Copy silverlight out of browser application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

After a user installs a silverlight app out of the browser, can they copy the application to another computer? If so, are there any good strategies to avoid this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've not tried it, I don't see why they couldn't.

I'm assuming they could just browse to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser` and copy the xap file. All that's left to do is call sllauncher.exe to install it on the new computer.

```
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe"
                          /install:"C:\Temp\Example.xap"
                          /origin:"http://www.someurl.com/silverlight"
                          /shortcut:desktop
```

I'm not aware of any strategy you could employ to prevent this.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. It seems that I need the origin url:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: Oops, right you are. I've edited my answer to include the origin parameter